# Beginner Inheritance Issue C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm learning all about C# and arrived at the Inheritance part. So I first wrote the following base class

```
class Soldier
{
    public int _health = 0;
    public int id = 0;
    public int level = 0;
    public string name = "soldier";

    public void Identify(int h, int ID, int lvl, string n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Health: " + h + "\nid: " + ID + "\nLevel: " + lvl + "\nName: " + n);
    }
}
```

After that of course I wanted to create a simple SubClass to test everything out:

```
class Knight : Soldier
{
    level = 2;
    public void Ride(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " can ride a mount");
    }
}
```

But when I run the program it gives me an error "The name 'level' does not exist in current context".

I know I'm doing something wrong so I searched it up, found some cases where users had no problem overriding a property like I did, other added "base." before the property. But neither have worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a property, it's a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that code to be in the class [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors), for example:

```
class Knight : Soldier
{
    //class constructor here
    public Knight() 
    {
        level = 2;
    }

    public void Ride(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " can ride a mount");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What is happening here is that you are trying to set a class-level variable inside of a *class definition*, which is not allowed.  You can only declare and initialize class variables inside of the class scope.  To set a variable when a class is created, you need to set it inside of the constructor.

```
class Knight : Soldier
{
    public Knight() : base()
    {
       base.level = 2;
    }
    public void Ride(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name + " can ride a mount");
    }
}
```